# decltype rules define lvalue or prvalue

Tags: c++, decltype

decltype statement defines the type depends of its parameter :

> - category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields T&;
> - if the value category of expression is prvalue, then decltype yields T.

What is a difference and how extra parentheses works here?
How double parentheses makes lvalue category?

```
int a = 0;

decltype (a) b = a;
cout << is_same<decltype(b), int>::value << '\n';
decltype ((a)) c = a;
cout << is_same<decltype(c), int&>::value << '\n';
```

Comment: An "extra" parenthesis is parsed as an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decltype` has some [wonky rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) to enable you to express *exactly* what you want.

If the expression within `decltype` is the name of a variable/function (aka a *id-expression*), then the resulting type is the type of that variable/function.

Otherwise, if the expression is anything else and its an lvalue of type `T`, the resulting type is `T&`, or if its an prvalue of type `T`, the resulting type is `T`.